# How to find dynamically added element by data attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an element to which is dynamically applied data attribute like this

```
var tr = $('<tr>');
tr.data('template_id', 5);
table.find('tbody').append(tr);
```

Here we have our tr on the table.

...
Here we want to find our newly added tr by data attribute

```
var tr = table.find('[data-template_id="5"]');
console.log(tr) // tr.length = 0;
```

Unfortunately, we have no found tr this way.

Why it is getting this result?

Comment: What is `table` in your first code snip? I think you need `$('table')`

Comment: Yes. var table = $('table');

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue you have is that `data-*` attributes added via jQuery are stored in its internal cache. They are not available as attributes in the DOM. With that in mind, you can use `filter()` to achieve what you require:

```
var $tr = table.find('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('template_id') == 5;
});
console.log($tr.length);
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I did not know about 'filter' method yet. Very usefull.

Comment: or you can also add tr.attr('data-template_id', 5); and it works this way

Comment: @ZohaibHassan it may work, but you shouldn't use `attr()` to access `data()` attributes unless there is no alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tr.attr("data-template_id", 5)` instead of `tr.data('template_id', 5)`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use

```
tr.attr('template_id', 5);
```

Comment: This sets tr's attribute template_id to 5. The question is about finding by attr